# How do I go about with Amazon EC2 self deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2

I have a Amazon Ec2 architecture where I have multiple servers attached to a ELB server. I do manual scaling of servers and attach more servers as and when needed, depending on the traffic requirement.

I deploy my application using Capistrano and currently while attaching new servers I always have to manually check if the new server has new application version and if not, make a deployment to the new server.

I wanted to know if there is a cleaner practice of the new server auto updating itself with the new application codebase if it finds itself outdated. I tried to use Amazon CodeDeploy, but it does not solve my purpose. It just provides me a deployment management console. Does Amazon provide a way where when the server comes up, it tries to self deploy ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method for you might be to use a **User Data script** when your Amazon EC2 instances launch.

This involves providing a script that is automatically run when a new instance starts. This script could download and install software, register the new server with a central monitoring system, update a configuration, etc. Some companies use the scripts to launch a configuration management system such as Chef, Puppet or Ansible.

Here's some details:

- [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)
- [Windows User Data scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html#user-data-execution)

Another option is to use **pre-configured Amazon Machine Images (AMIs)**, which have all the new software already installed. Launching new instances from the updated AMI means they already have the software installed.

Of course, this would require creating a new AMI with every software release. Some companies have automated this process with tools like [Netflix Aminator](http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/03/ami-creation-with-aminator.html) and [Packer](https://packer.io/).